# Is it possible to use TotalTerminal with Go2Shell?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am using TotalTerminal. Now, I want to use Go2Shell, so that I can access quickly a terminal in the good folder.

But, when I click on the Go2Shell icon, it opens a usual Terminal and not a TotalTerminal shell.

Is there a way to use TotalTerminal with Go2Shell or to open in TotalTerminal a shell set to the current directory?

---

### EDIT

The first shell that I open with Go2Shell opens in the Visor of TotalTerminal. But, then, if I just "escape" to close the Visor (instead of "command-W"), the next shell opens in a separate window.

So, my question boils down to:

**Is it possible to have multiple windows (or tabs) in the Visor of TotalTerminal?**

See also [my other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/120566/44947) on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open TotalTerminal settings (Terminal → Preferences → TotalTerminal).
2. Create the Visor profile if it doesn't exist already:

   [image]
3. Go to the settings tab, then the Visor profile.
4. Select the Shell tab, and enter the following:

   ```
   cd "$(osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)')"
   ```

   [image]
5. Quit and re-open Terminal.

Now, when opening Visor, it will cd to the directory in the current Finder window.

Comment: Thanks! It's great but not what I am looking for. Your trick works only the first time I open TotalTerminal (with the hot key). Anyway, good to know!

Comment: @Colas With the visor open, press ⌘W to close it rather than your hotkey to hide it. This actually closes the visor window, so that next time you open it, it's a new shell and runs the script again.

Comment: Now, I understand what is going on. I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Colas Please don't fall into the trap of [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) :)

Comment: OK Sorry :) pfff I'm tired

Answer (score 1):

*Ask a two part question, get a four-part answer!*

Lets recap.

Original question:

> Is there a way to use TotalTerminal with Go2Shell or to open in TotalTerminal a shell set to the current directory?

'Boiled' question:

> Is it possible to have multiple windows (or tabs) in the Visor of TotalTerminal?
>   (Very related to your linked second question, I think.)

---

Original, and boiled answer: Yes, and sure: In fact, here, [I've written you a little app](https://gist.github.com/g-nix/8974151).

It's an Automator applet with an unholy mixture of shell, AppleScript, and a couple System Events triggers. ***Lots of caveats, a few instructions:***

- [*Some of this can be changed by editing the script(s) — open the program in Automator.*]
- `⌘`-drag into Finder toolbar to "install".
- You must have TotalTerminal open (i.e., the menu bar icon) prior to using this.
- You will need to "enable access for Assistive Devices" (<=10.8), or authorize "System Events" in Security/Accessibility pane (10.9). It will prompt you.
- Your Visor trigger must be `⌘ /`
- Your default profile must be 'Visor'.
- Your startup action must be "new window with settings: Visor".
- It doesn't work 100% like Go2Shell, as something in Finder must be **selected** — if it seems to not be working, make sure you've clicked something. Mostly only affects icon view.
- Probably a couple other things I'm forgetting. If you decide to use this and can't get it to work, let me know. It *does* work.

---

### But:

You probably **don't** want to use this.
  If I can take the liberty of guessing your *underlying* question, I think it might be something to the effect of:

> I'm using the Terminal a lot these days, and I've found TotalTerminal to be very useful. But its also limited in a lot of ways. How can I do [this/that/the other]?

(I'm venturing that is basically the case since I found myself in that same situation not all that long ago.)

---

### So, probably a better answer:

(In my own opinion and experience.)

Simply by virtue of the fact that you're asking these questions, and its important enough to you to post a bounty, I think It's probably time to upgrade to a [more powerful terminal emulator](http://www.iterm2.com). You might have looked at iTerm before, perhaps found its configuration/preferences to be cumbersome, and yes, that's not one of its strongest points. But once you overcome that, it makes up for it manyfold in power and flexibility. It's absolutely worth investing the time to figure it out, since it can do what you're asking now, and probably what's you'll be asking *next* as well.

Just a couple examples:

- *multiple* system-wide hotkeys for flexible "visors", with customizable settings for each.
- Recursive split panes, as well as tabs.
- Go2Shell supports it fine: `open -a Go2Shell --args config`, select iTerm2.
- Doesn't require hacking Terminal.app by injecting code.
- Lots more (look under the help menu).

Quick and dirty demo (animated gif, click to expand):

[image: iTerm "Visor" Demo]

If anyone is wondering what magic they're seeing here:

That's [iTerm](http://www.iterm2.com) (with a profile with a system hotkey), the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) theme, [fish](http://fishshell.com), and [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager).

---

Hopefully, you'll find something that works well for your workflow: if not, keep looking.

More or less, someone's always already done it — you just have to find it!

Comment: What I like with TotalTerminal is that it's window can stay on the top of all windows. Can iTerm achieve this?

Comment: Yes, there's something called a 'hotkey window'. At the very bottom left of the 'Keys' preference pane, there's a checkbox that says 'Hotkey window hides when focus is lost'. This does the same thing as a 'pinned' visor window.

Comment: I tried `iTerm 2` but have the following issue. Maybe you can tell. In `TotalTerminal`, the hotkey opens a window that stays on the top of over windows and does not close unless I explicitly ask, even if I change applications (if I go to the Finder for instance). Whereas with `iTerm 2`, the hotkey window closes when I go to the Finder. Is it possible to make `iTerm 2` behaving as `TotalTerminal`. Thanks.

Comment: So, you have 'Hotkey window hides when focus is lost' **unchecked** it still closes the window?

Comment: I don't find this option. Are you using `iTerm 2`?