# How can I set a shortcut to close the window of TotalTerminal

Tags: keyboard, terminal

TotalTerminal is great. But, if it is not the active application, in order to close its window, I have to enter again the application.

Is it possible to set a shortcut to close the window of TotalTerminal, even if it is not the active application?

To close it, presently, I have to make it active and then press `escape`. But, if possible, I would like to have also a shortcut for `command+W`.

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer [to your other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120920/65379) largely applies here too, but to specifically answer this:

If you tick the checkbox in the TotalTerminal preferences to `show icon in Status Menu`,  it should allow you to `⌘-w` and reactivate without having to relaunch. You might also be running into issues with it *seemingly* not reactivating due to conflicting shortcuts in various applications, in which case I recommend trying a modifier-only "hotkey". ⌥ + ⌥ seems to work well.